# Return a Table and Use a Cursor to Print Billing Items and Find Total

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a function that returns a table with a hotel guest's personal information (the function should print out the guest's personal information ONLY ONCE per bill) and uses a cursor to print each billing item as well as a final total. Simply, I'm trying to print a guest's hotel bill.  A single guest may have multiple bills for multiple stays.  Unfortunately, it is required that I use a cursor.

Here's my code so far. My code is not going to compile because I didn't know what to put for some parts.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.fn_ProduceBill', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
DROP FUNCTION dbo.fn_ProduceBill;

GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_ProduceBill(@FolioID smallint)
RETURNS @Result TABLE
(
    GuestFirst varchar(20), GuestLast varchar(20), GuestAddress1 varchar(30), GuestAddress2 varchar(10), GuestCity varchar(20), GuestState char(2), GuestPostalCode char(10), CheckinDate smalldatetime, RoomNumber varchar(5)
)

AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO @Result
SELECT G.GuestFirst, G.GuestLast, G.GuestAddress1, G.GuestAddress2, G.GuestCity, G.GuestState, G.GuestPostalCode, F.CheckinDate, R.RoomNumber
FROM Folio F, Guest G, Room R
WHERE F.GuestID = G.GuestID
AND F.RoomID = R.RoomID
AND F.FolioID = @FolioID;

RETURN

END

DECLARE @BillingCategoryID smallint
DECLARE @BillingAmount smallmoney

DECLARE BillingCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT BillingCategoryID, BillingAmount
FROM Billing
WHERE FolioID = @FolioID  --ERROR: Must declare scalar variable @FolioID

OPEN BillingCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM BillingCursor
INTO @BillingCategoryID, @BillingAmount

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

--How do I add each billing amount?????

SELECT @BillingCategoryID, @BillingAmount
FROM --?

FETCH NEXT FROM BillingCursor
INTO @BillingCategoryID, @BillingAmount

END

CLOSE BillingCursor

DEALLOCATE BillingCursor
```

Comment: 1. Don't use cursor. It will give you bad performance. 2. You need to show us your table schema and expected result

Comment: First of all, the first mentioned error results from the variable @ FolioID being declared in the scope of the function only. So if you want to use it outside the function, you Need to declare it for this scope as well. Now, what do you mean with "add each billing amount"? You already fetch it into @ BillingAmount within your Loop - so you should be able to read it from there. Or did I miss anything in your query?

Comment: Cursors could be useful, but I can't see any reason to use it here. But you haven't shown the expected results either so it's hard to tell.